# Debugging xcode phase?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm getting one error, Ive made a UIPageController for the web but I cant seem to find the problem with it, there is only one error, please help. code bellow - more code on demand.

```
@interface ContentViewController ()
@end
@implementation ContentViewController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[_webView loadHTMLString: _dataObject baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end

[_webView loadHTMLString: _dataObject baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];
```

My "Error is above"

Please help

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@end
```

Comment: What was the error? Do you want to load HTML from string or a URL?

Comment: Could you show error message?

Comment: the error is "No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the sector 'loadHTML_string:baseURL:'

Comment: Can you show your .h file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the .h file to this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@end
```

Beside that if you want to load a webpage in UIWebView from a url then you can do like this:

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit =YES; // This will fit the page within the screen
NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/xxx/xxx"];
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:Url];
[self.webView loadRequest:req];
```

If you want to load a HTML file from document then do:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Or if you just want to load a string then do:

```
NSString* htmlString = @"";
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: Thank you - But I have a bigger problem now: I need this thing i made to switch between 2 screens with the Page control buttons at the bottom and without the curl! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eFvIXDujb0